# Disable Select on a ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

I would like to disable the ListView's Select command based upon other data in the row.  For example, if the UserStatus is "T", I'd like to gray out the Select hyperlink and prevent selection of that row.

I've accomplished the same thing in a GridView by the following statement in the RowCreated event.  However, I haven't been able to rework that code for a ListView.

```
CType(e.Row.Controls(0), WebControl).Attributes("disabled") = "true"
```

---

```
<asp:listview runat="server" id="ListView">

<itemtemplate>
  <tr id="rowUsers" runat="server">
    <td><asp:linkbutton id="btnEdit" runat="server" text="Select" onclick="btnEdit_Click" /></td>
    <td><asp:label id="UserNameLabel" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>' /></td>
    <td><asp:label id="UserStatusLabel" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("UserStatus") %>' /></td>
  </tr>
</itemtemplate>
```

---

Generated output...

```
<tr id="ListView_rowUsers_0">
  <td><a id="ListView_btnEdit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ListView$ctrl0$btnEdit','')">Select</a></td>
  <td><span id="ListView_UserNameLabel_0">Adams,John P</span></td>
  <td><span id="ListView_UserStatusLabel_0">T</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use ItemDataBound event and do a FindControl("btnEdit") and simply set the Enabled property.

How to use [ListView ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx#Y384) event.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CType(e.Item.Controls(0), WebControl).Attributes("disabled") = "disabled"
```

on ListView's `ItemCreated`

Comment: The e.row wasn't recognized as was WebControl for the ListView. I tried e.Item and LiteralControl, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

in your item template you can use the databinding syntax to disable the button

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton id="btnEdit" runat="server" text="Select" 
                  Enabled=<%# Eval("UserStatus") == "T" %> />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I used the answer from gbs above, I'm sure the data binding syntax would also work.  I got hung up on the ItemCreated event since that worked for the GridView.